# part after '_' in data returned is PascalCase even though I set camelCase as the default naming convention

Tags: breeze

I have this line of code before I create my entity manager:

`breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();`

and this query:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('vehicle')
                .expand("engine, driveType")
                .select("engine.friendlyEngineName, driveType.friendlyDrivetrain")
```

The data comes back like so:

```
driveType_FriendlyDriveTrain = "Rear Wheel"
engine_FriendlyEngineName = "6.2L V8"
```

Why are "FriendlyDriveTrain" and "FriendlyEngineName" PascalCase? This seems clearly wrong since I set camelCase before I created the EntityManager and the query. How do I make it so that the parts after the '_' are camelCase as well?

**note**: I made sure to remove any web api json formatting configurations so that breeze is the only one managing the translation.

**edit**: The weird thing is that this same query returns properties that are camelCase after the '_' when it hits the cache. So same query, two different results.

Comment: What it has to do with knockout.js?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [**documentation on NamingConvention**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/naming-convention). If that doesn't clear it up, you can come back and ask a more specific question. Thanks.

### Edit 2 Sept 2014 (morning)

Please also explain what you think Breeze should be doing with the "_" character. The Breeze convention treats it like any other identifier character (e.g., a-z,A-Z,0-9) and does nothing with it. It seems you want your convention to skip over leading underscores and lower the case of the first char thereafter if it is alpha. I think you also want to drop the underscores ... but I'm not sure.

That's cool. You can write your own NamingConvention that does what you want. And you can make it the default too. In fact, the `noUnderscoreConvention` shown on the NamingConvention documentation page is more than half way home for you.

I will say you threw me for a loop with your mix of periods and underscores in the `select` statement and returned data. I have no idea how you got the select to work or got that kind of result.

### Edit 2 Sept 2014 (afternoon)

Ok ... I overlooked the fact that you are doing a ***projection***!

The projection flattens dotted property path values (whether ComplexType or EntityType navigations). It creates projected property names for these "flattened properties" by using "_" as the separator character. Yes, it applies the applicable MetadataStore's naming convention to those "_" separated names and, yes, the Breeze camelCase convention doesn't do anything special with the underscore. So you get back flattened projection property names such as "engine_FriendlyEngineName".

You can call this a bug if you like. I don't. I don't because (a) it seems to me a matter of opinion as to what a camelCase convention should do in this situation; (b) it's been this way forever; and (c) I don't think it is important enough to risk breaking existing applications that might rely on the current behavior ... not when your remedy is so simple.

And that remedy is to write your own camelCase convention that handles these projected property names differently.

> Please include it here when you write it so that others who share your perspective may benefit from it.

I'm not sure what you mean when you write: "*this same query returns properties that are camelCase after the '_' when it hits the cache*". What query is that? Not the one you wrote here.

Projection results don't "*hit the cache*" ... unless the projected property value is itself an entity ... and that is NOT the case here. What do you mean by "*this same query*". I await your response.

Comment: I read the docs and nothing in there talked about the part after the '_' in the data returned. I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: None of the properties in our data model have underscores in them. The underscores are being added by breeze. When we select complex types (i.e. engine.friendlyEngineName) it creates a property with an underscore in it.